# How to add different headers to different pages while printing using css?

Tags: html, css, printing

I am adding headers while printing the page with css `@media print`. It works fine but repeats the same content in all of the pages. I wanted to add different content to different pages.

**For eg : I have "name1" in the header of the first page, then I should have "name2" in the header of second page.**

Comment: add more details, and post code to show what you have tried so far. [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)